# How to display Y axis in degrees

Tags: plotting, ticks

How to display on my [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) $Y$ axis in degrees?
my function:

```
Plot[ArcSin[A*Sin[x Degree]], {x, 0, 50}]
```

I tried:

```
Plot[ArcSin[A*Sin[x Degree]] Degree, {x, 0, 50}]
```

But it does not change the $Y$ axis correctly.

thanks a lot for help

Comment: X axis works fine - it's in degrees. The problem is with an Y-axis which i wanto have in degs but is still with rad.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

straight forward simple answer:

```
Plot[ArcSin[A*Sin[x Degree]]/Degree, {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`Degree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Degree.html),

> gives the number of radians in one degree. It has a numerical value of π/180.

So it has units of radians per degree. If you have something in radians, and need to convert it to degrees you should divide  by `Degree`.

Now, to have the axis Ticks to show the `Degree` symbol `°` (`\[Degree]`), you need to define tick marks drawn with the specified labels. See in the details of [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) . Here I use the function

```
tickf = {#, StringJoin[ToString[#], "\[Degree]"]} &
```

and take advantage of [`FindDivisions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html).

```
With[
 {
  A = 3,
  tickf = {#, StringJoin[ToString[#], "\[Degree]"]} &
  },
 Plot[
  A*Sin[x Degree]
  , {x, 0, 360}
  , Ticks -> {
    tickf /@ FindDivisions[{0, 360, 45}, 8],
    Automatic
    }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[
 {
  A = 3,
  tickf = {#, StringJoin[ToString[#], "\[Degree]"]} &
  },
 Plot[
  ArcSin[A*Sin[x Degree]]/Degree
  , {x, 0, 20}
  , Ticks -> {
    tickf /@ FindDivisions[{0, 20}, 4],
    tickf /@ FindDivisions[{0, 100}, 8]
    }
  , PlotRange -> {All, {0, 100}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Create Ticks in Degrees for corresponding radian values

```
dticks = Table[{k, k 180./Pi}, {k, -3, 3, 0.5}]
```

Use the created ticks inside Plot

```
Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -1, 1}, Ticks -> {Automatic, dticks}]
```

[image]